# How do I print from the reader app on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader

I've been trying to print on my Windows 7 computer. Whenever I go to print anything it goes straight to the reader. When I right click it gives me no printing options. It doesn't have the "devices" button either. Please help! What do I do?